# Unwanted component method execution during a mouse click event

Tags: html, angular

I'm currently working on a component that displays a list of items using material grid list and material cards, where an item will be displayed only if it is exists in a given datasource. So far I am getting the result I need, but upon further inspection, I tried to log the method that I am calling to check if the item exists into the console and that's where I discovered that anytime I click on the page during testing/debugging, the method gets executed. I am just worried if this will somehow affect the performance of the app.

I haven't specifically tried anything yet as I am still unaware how this is happening (I am a beginner to angular, please bear with me)

HTML

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight=".85:1">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngIf="item.isActive">
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z10 item-card">
          <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{item.title}}</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{item.subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card-header>
          <img mat-card-image src="{{item.icon}}" alt="{{item.name}}">
          <mat-card-content>{{item.description}}</mat-card-content>
          <mat-divider [inset]="true"></mat-divider>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-button 
            [disabled]="!isAccessible(item.name)">Action1</button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </div>
</mat-grid-list>
```

COMPONENT

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  items: any;
  dataSource: ItemDataSource; //items from the back end server

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = fromConfig.ITEMS;

    this.dataSource = new ItemDataSource(this.store);
    this.dataSource.load();
  }

  isAccessible(itemName: string) {
    return this.dataSource.isAccessible(itemName);
  }
}
```

DATASOURCE

```
export class ItemDataSource implements DataSource<Item> {

  itemSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {  }

  isAccessible(itemName: string): boolean { 
    let exists = false;

    for (const itemSubject of this.itemSubject.value) {
      console.log('Parameter Item Name: ' + itemName + '; Subject Item Name: ' + itemSubject.name);
      if (itemSubject.name === itemName ) {
        exists = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return exists;
  }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.itemSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.itemSubject.complete();
  }
}
```

Expected result would be that the method will be executed only once during initialization or after refresh.

Comment: You shouldn't call functions from templates because function calls trigger on each change detection cycle, and clicks, among other things, trigger change detection.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the insight @ritaj. Can I ask how or what I should do to somehow implement it better?

Comment: Just bind `isAccessible` boolean flag to the `item` in `items` itself. And resolve it like `this.items = this.items.forEach(item => item.isAccessible === // Some logic);`

Comment: I will definitely try to look into that. Thank you @ritaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using square brackets bind the *disable* property of the button. This binds the function with that button state. So, the function is called every time the page is being rendered. To use the function only once (as you intended), remove the braces.

```
<button mat-button disabled="!isAccessible(item.name)">Action1</button>
```

This will call the function only once when the page is rendered intially.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! Every tutorial I have seen or read has never explained it to me that way or maybe I wasn't paying attention to it at all.

Comment: I'm happy that it helped you :)